# How can I reload the Ethernet service (without stopping the current connection)?

Tags: 18.04, bash, ethernet, services

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04, and I need to `reload` the Ethernet service (only the Ethernet one) without stopping the current Internet Connection (download/upload).

I need to use only then the Bash command-line.

I found different answers to similar questions, but no one worked for me, the best one stopped the service without a restart (but I need a `reload` NOT a restart).

I suppose that the Network-Manager service can create some troubles when trying to work with the Ethernet interface via command-line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

## systemctl reload networking

or

## systemctl reload networking.service

Comment: just done, but first, this will reload ALL the networking service and not only the Ethernet one, and after I receive the following error:
`Failed to reload networking.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit networking.service.
See ... systemctl status ... for details.
systemctl status networking
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since ... 11h ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 30341 (code=exited, status=0)`